# Spring MVC Rest / JSON service

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, controller

I just tried adding this to my sample controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/jsontest", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody User getUserAsJson() {

        User jsonUser = new User();
        jsonUser.setFirstName("Mickey");
        jsonUser.setLastName("Mouse");
        jsonUser.setUsername("mmous");


        return jsonUser;
    }
```

However, visiting the /jsontest url ends on a 406 http error => not acceptable.

So... what's the currently working method for producing "application/json" responses, instead of returning jsp/html views?

I'm using Spring Framework 3.0.6 RELEASE.

Comment: Do you have [`jackson.jar`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) on your CLASSPATH and are you calling `/jsontest` with `Accept: application/json`?

Comment: 1) How can I add jackson.jar as a Maven depedency?

Comment: 2) I DON'T want to call with "Accept:", I want json response, always!

Comment: I added an answer. Note that if your browser is sending `application/xml` then you cannot simply return JSON, Spring MVC will return 406 for you. But if your browser sends a wildcard accepted type, Spring MVC will pick first available, let it be JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) mapper to your CLASSPATH:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And call your web service with correct accept header, e.g.:

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/json" localhost:8080/app/jsontest
```

Or using [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) from browser.

Comment: thank you Tomasz, I understand but... why does it pick Json as the deafult return format? I mean... where is that written? I read something about httpmessageconverters but didn't understood. :(

Comment: Without going into details, this logic is encoded in an obscure[`writeWithMessageConverters`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.web.servlet/3.0.6/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java#AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.writeWithMessageConverters(java.lang.Object%2Corg.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage%2Corg.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage)). Put a breakpoint there and see how it works.

Comment: nice! So can I assert "@ResponseBody returning a String will return text/plain AND @ResponseBody returning a bean will return application/json" ?

Comment: As you can see it depends on your CLASSPATH. If it works this way in your project, I think that's a valid assumption.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/jsontest", method=RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody User getUserAsJson() {

        User jsonUser = new User();
        jsonUser.setFirstName("Mickey");
        jsonUser.setLastName("Mouse");
        jsonUser.setUsername("mmous");


        return jsonUser;
    }
```

This should work add produces attribute..