# Spring Rest Service

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm working with example from https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ and I changed default class Greeting to my own class and, when I'm calling this in web browser http://localhost:8080/greeting I get answer:
`There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
Could not find acceptable representation`

My controller:

```
package rest;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import database.*;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
    private DBAccess dbaccess= new DBAccess();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Customer greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new  Customer(1,"a","b");
    }
}
```

And customer class:

```
package database;

public class Customer {
    private long id;
    private  String firstName, lastName;

    public Customer(){};
    public Customer(long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


    void setFirstName(String firstName){
        this.firstName=firstName;
    }

    void setLastName(String lastName){
        this.lastName=lastName;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

following [Spring MVC Rest / JSON service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136926/spring-mvc-rest-json-service) I added jackson mapper dependency but it doesn't works...

Please help me

According to nebula comment.
I haven't web.xml, I'm using example from https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ and there isn't any.

Here is my Application.class

```
package rest;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `web.xml`? Also there is no packages provided for component scan. Should be something like `@ComponentScan("rest")` if rest is your base package.

Comment: no I haven't web.xml. After change to  @ComponentScan("rest") it still gives the same error... :(

Comment: If you don't have web.xml then there should be a class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer`. Do you have such class?

Comment: Hold on. Are you trying with Spring boot following that tutorial?

Comment: I'm following this tutorial and in pom.xml I've `<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>` so i guess yes Im using Spring boot

Comment: @Bartek can you please put the stack trace from your application log when this error occurs ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a JsonMappingException.

I think you need to add getters/setters or make some attributes public, because Jackson is probably confused when serializing your Customer class.

Comment: Give this a try, add public getters. I thing Brian is right.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define method and response type.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody
public Customer greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
```

Also make sure it is correctly mapped as  `http://localhost:8080/greeting`

Comment: still the same error. When I'm using Greeting class (default) it works so I think it's mapped correctly

Comment: Can you update your question with `web.xml` or application configuration class which ever applicable on your case?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@ResponseBody` annotation for your `greeting` method as following

```
 @RequestMapping("/greeting") 
 public @ResponseBody Customer greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
     return new  Customer(1,"a","b"); 
 }
```

It is used for object serialization. It will try to convert return value (customer object) and write it to the http response automatically.

Comment: It's a `@RestController` already, no need to add `@ResponseBody`

Answer (score 0):

I am under the impression the lack of getters for your private fields in your Customer might cause the trouble

Besides, have you added the JSON path dependency in your pom.xml?

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spring Boot? If you are, your Application class should be annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. This bundles the `@EnableWebMvc`, `@Configuration`, `@ComponentScan`and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotations. A stacktrace would be helpful to try figure out exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score -1):

change your

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

To

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GreetingController.class, args);
    }
```